# Identifying the bugs in my JavaScript code: "i is already defined"

Tags: javascript

I am writing code while following `Gordon Zhu's WatchandCode tutorial` at [watchandcode.com](https://watchandcode.com/). I am pretty new but trying to solve as much as I can on my own, but I have been stuck here for days.

To check my own code issues arise, I pause the videos and go through my code character by character to see if I have typed anything differently. Sometimes I do catch something; for instance, there was a time my variable didn't work because the syntax was written as Var: instead of var = .

I am also not able to use the debugger in the chrome console, but I suppose that is for a different question.

In the picture included below you can see three error messages: At line `38` it says `forgotten debugger statement?` which we can ignore for this question. The real focus of this article is on lines `47` and `51`, which say `'i' is already defined`. I have looked at these for loops and the nesting seems correct. I'm not sure why it would say this.

Tools I am using/have used/have tried to use: Plnkr.co(am using), jshint.com (used), and the chrome console (tried)

[code in plnkr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhX9T.png)

Comment: you defined it in row 41...
you need no redefine in row 47 and 51

Comment: if there are any errors being put out by the console at runtime, please include them. You should be able to use chrome console, even if your debugger statement in your source isn't working, by hitting f12 or ctrl(cmd) + i.

Comment: You should include your code right here. An external image is not convenient at all...

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Code always needs to be in the question itself. Do not use screenshots to include text in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variables in javascript have a function scope. Your linter is complaining that you have already defined var i on line 41. This actually won't cause any issues when you try to execute the code because while declarations are hoisted, assignments are not.

The linter is just letting you know that all three of these are technically the same i as it is a thing which could cause problems if you were using it for more than a simple incrementor.